# asp.net core 2.0 deployment - InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Recently I developed a asp.net core 2.0 web app in my company and in debug mode works perfect, however when I deployed in our testing server into IIS and we try to execute from a client machine it ran into a problem:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
CryptographicException: The key {0851ad3b-df33-4cf7-8c3a-5c637adaa713} was not found in the key ring.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, bool allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, out UnprotectStatus status)

InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(string serializedToken)
```

The problem starts when I submmit login page. I investigated links with same problems here and other blogs, but I found that has to be with ValidateAntiForgeryToken and solution is related with Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection. I added nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Redis to my project and I added in ConfigureServices of startup class following code:

```
    var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("192.168.10.151:80");
    services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");
    services.AddOptions();
```

Our testing server ip is 192.168.10.151, however app throws following exception:

```
RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. InternalFailure on PING
```

¿Why it doesn't connect since is resolving in the same web app server?
¿Where is DataProtection-Keys database located?

as a workaround, I changed method by using PersistKeysToFileSystem as follows:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
                .SetApplicationName("myapp-portal")
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo (@"c:\ProgramData\dpkeys"));
```

However running app in test server 192.168.10.151, when login form is submitted, goes back to login page. Checking stdout log file, only shows:

Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OmniPays
Now listening on: http://localhost:30064
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Checking network messages by chrome's developers tools I noticed something:

Request URL: http://192.168.10.151/OmniPays/Account/Login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 192.168.10.151:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

and then ...

Request URL: http://192.168.10.151/OmniPays/Home/Main
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 192.168.10.151:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

AccountController's Login action redirect request to HomeController's Main action only if authentication succeded, and Main action has [Authorize] attribute. For some reasons I can't achieve understand, Main action fails and return to Login page. URL in chrome shows: http://192.168.10.151/OmniPays/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FOmniPays%2FHome%2FMain

I'm using Microsoft Identity. In debug mode works fine and if I deploy app in my local PC on IIS also works fine. ¿Maybe any SDK is missing in the server?

Please need help!!

Comment: Is your redis server really running on port 80?

Comment: I'm newbie about it, ¿redis server is another app web server implementation?

Comment: Redis is a cache server, similar to a database but typically everythign is stored in memory unless you specific tell it to persist.  It's default port is 6379. https://redis.io/

Comment: So, it's not a must to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection?, If I don't use this library, the default is that keys is managed in memory? In that case, why app is returning back to login page and it seems [Authorize] is failing?

Comment: do you have multiple @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in the view by chance? Should only need one if so. Does the controller action have [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]?

Comment: As far as Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, I don't think @bhmahler is saying go away from that, but the redis part isn't needed if you're not actually using redis.

Comment: It really depends on what you are storing. If none of the data would be considered sensitive then I suppose you wouldn't need it.  That being said, protecting any data is usually a good practice. Have you tried setting the port to 6379 for the redis connection to see if it is available on the default port?

Comment: bhmahler, no redis server available so I don't need it. On the other hand, answering to Robert, I have no multiples antiforgerytoken in views, in fact, none antiforgery tokens were set explicitly because net core add them by default in post requests as far as I know, and all controllers action related with post have [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]. Deploying in my local IIS pc (developer pc) and I execute http://<ip>/OmniPays/ locally or remotely, works perfect including [Authorize] validation (I'm using Microsoft Identity) when login. IIS server login [Authorize] fails and goes back (User is null)

Comment: just as a test, can you try adding @Html.AntiForgeryToken() as the first element in your form and see if that changes the behavior at all?

Comment: Robert I added @Html.AntiForgeryToken() and fails [Authorize] when executing app remotely, from a client pc, but works fine when app is executed into host server browser. [Authorize] validation is failing (Microsoft Identity).

Comment: var resultSigIn = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: true);
return resultSigIn.Succeeded in all cases (Locally or remotely). So to verify userName and IsAuthenticated values, when login is succeded, it redirects to Main action of HomeController, code just to test values is: throw new Exception($"UserName: {User.Identity.Name}, Authenticated: {User.Identity.IsAuthenticated}"); Executing into Host Server, shows: UserName: accarvajal, Authenticated: True. When app is exec remotely, shows: Exception: UserName: , Authenticated: False.

Comment: Configure in Startup.cs: var host = Configuration.GetSection("CustomSettings").GetSection("RedisServer")["Ip"]; services.AddDataProtection()              .SetApplicationName("omnipays-portal")                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo($@"\\{host}\dpkeys")); services.AddOptions();
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(o =>                o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OmniPaysConnection"))); services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Comment: services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options =>
{ options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");                        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");                        options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout");                 });

Answer (score 4):

Solution was found! the cause of problem was not in IIS neither the Server, connection to the server is using http rather than https, no certifies involved to validate secure connection, however testing in differents servers app works ok, so I felt really disappointed. Solution was to remove cookies an any data related with this URL pointing to Development Server (failing) in all browsers, data that was previously stored, and voila!!, now app works perfect. By default, as bhmahler comments data protection is made in memory and I left configuration by default, I mean, not explicitly persistence in redis nor PersistKeysToFileSystem and works fine, however is important to set DataProtection to strong data sensitive protection.

I'm newbie about these topics and It's unbelievable such a simple thing caused on me that waste of time. Thanks to all!.